# How to change the pixel position of the TabPanel extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3, extjs-mvc

Can anyone please tell how to change the pixel position of the Tabpanel in extjs

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not clear, tell what you have done?

if you want to place your tab panel at center use a layout. if you are using border layout place it in center region. check http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/layout/border.html